# ui-bootstrap Angular modal resolve and Scope value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am relatively new to angular and I have integrated Bootstrap modal to my project but I am not able to use the value from "programcontroller".

I want **id_program** from **"programcontroller"** inside the **"ModalInstanceCtrl"** controller. I tried adding it in the **RESOLVE** but I was not able to get the data.

I got the hardcoded data using the RESOLVE from **"programcontroller"** successfully inside **"ModalInstanceCtrl"** controller of modal.

But since I get the id_prgram using this snipet:

```
<input type="text" ng-hide=" true" ng-model="id_program" ng-init="id_program=item._id">
```

The above code is inside ng-repeat block and gets populated. I do know that it is because of asynchronous that causes the problem.

I have attached the code for your reference.

```
catalogapp.controller('programcontroller', function ($scope, $uibModal, $log, $routeParams) {

$scope.id_program = "";

$scope.title_program = "";

$scope.filter_program = $routeParams.seasonId;

$scope.season_number = $routeParams.seasonNumber;

$scope.model = {
//got this from previous HTML page as routeparams
    season_id : $routeParams.seasonId
}
$scope.animationsEnabled = true;

$scope.program_array = [
    {
        "_id" : "program:a8097ae943bdbd372906ea494ddecbf2",
        "series" : "series:fcde9691e624ba50df9be71735f4bb14",
        "title" : "title1",
        "season" : "season:a6e4d728c316cdffa933490d4f538251",

    },
    {
        "_id" : "urn:esp:hbo:program:testprogram20160310",
        "title" : "title1",
        "series" : "series:4f19358c7377482f1310e5cfa06c5bd2",
        "season" : "season:a6e4d728c316cdffa933490d4f538251",
    }
]

$scope.items = [
    {
        "title" : "title",
        "_id" : "program:version:2541203f297f8f0d",
        "shortTitle" : "shtitle",
        "program" : "program:f555feb8dafc1bae42d",
    },
    {
        "title" : "title2",
        "_id" : "program:version:40a2313f297f8f0d",
        "shortTitle" : "shtitle2",
        "program" : "program:f55asfsa57927411bd6545feb8dafc1bae42d",
    },
    {
        "title" : "title3",
        "_id" : "program:version:403f297f8f0d",
        "shortTitle" : "shtitle3",
        "program" : "program:asdf5557927411bd6545feb8dafc1bae42d",
    }
]

$scope.open = function (size) {
    var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
        size: size,
        backdrop: 'static',
        resolve: {
            items1: function () {
                return $scope.items;
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
        $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
}

});


catalogapp.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $uibModalInstance, items1) {
    $scope.items = items1;

    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');


      };
});
```

HTML Code is given below!!!!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HBO ESP Console</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.9/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/main.css">
    <script src="/controllers/programcontroller.js"></script>


</head>
<body style="background-color:#44484a">
    <h2>Program List</h2>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <body ng-controller="ModalInstanceCtrl">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">Program Version</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" style="float:left">
                <ul ng-repeat="item in items" style="list-style-type:none">
                    <li class="image">
                        <button type="button" style="background-color: #555555" class="btn btn-default">
                            <img ng-src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/atti12/tv-series-folder/512/Game-of-Thrones-icon.png" height="200" width="200" />
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </body>
    </script>

    <div ng-controller="programcontroller">
        <input ng-hide=" true" type="text" ng-model="filter_program"><br><br>
        <p ng-hide=" true">Season_id: {{model.season_id}}</p>
        <p style="font-size:18px">Season Number:{{season_number}}</p>
        <div style="float:left">
            <div style="float:left">
                <ul ng-repeat=" item in program_array | filter : filter_program" style=" list-style-type:none;float:left">
                    <li class="image">
                        <input type="text" ng-hide=" true" ng-model="id_program" ng-init="id_program=item._id">
                        <input type="text" ng-hide=" true" ng-model="title_program" ng-init="title_program=item.title">
                        <button type="button" style="background-color: #555555" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">
                            <img ng-src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/atti12/tv-series-folder/512/Game-of-Thrones-icon.png" height="200" width="200" />
                        </button>
                        <p>{{item.title}}</p>
                        {{id_program}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

PLEASE help me with this guys!!!!!! Thanks

Comment: Hi can you add a link to codepen or JSBin with your code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the filter value even before angular has processed it.

Here is the solution

```
<ul ng-repeat="it in itm">
<li>
  {{it._id}}
  <input type="text" ng-hide="true" >
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="setFilter(it._id);open('lg')">Large modal --- {{it._id}}</button>
</li>
</ul>
```

Controller

```
$scope.setFilter = function (filterValue) {
   $scope.filter = filterValue;
```

}

Here is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LB6jcNrJ5Yi8dYe4xTw9?p=preview)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Still not working!!! all the dependencies are up to date and not to be bothered with I guess as I double checked things...!!

Comment: Can you create a plunkr or JSBin or Codepen with your code ??

Comment: In the above code I need the **filter value from ModalDemoCtrl** inside the **ModalInstanceCtrl**....Can you help me with this

Comment: you are trying to access the filter value even before angular as processed and set the value.And as much as possible try to avoid JQuery way of programming.Any ways here is the solution

http://plnkr.co/edit/LB6jcNrJ5Yi8dYe4xTw

Answer (score 0):

remove ng-controller="ModalInstanceCtrl" from

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
```

and see what happens.

Comment: take a look at this plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/QUIFQMqkI256EYpHKRPS?p=preview and let me know if you need any explanation. The problem was that id_program is a string and is bound to multiple input in ng-repeat.